# Typescript error using library react components: TS2769

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, electron

I have an ejected CRA with electron that I have been trying to convert .js|.jsx files to .ts|.tsx. The steps I followed are:

1. add a tsconfig.json file to my project root directory.
2. npm install various @types/** dependencies
3. add ts-loader and source-map-loader to webpack.config.js
4. change file extension to main electron process: electron.js and renderer process: renderer.js to .ts and .tsx respectively

While I am able to run the app with `npm start` with just changing my main process file: electron.js to electron.ts as well as the renderer process file: renderer.js to renderer.tsx, I am unable to resolve issues and conflicts that occur when converting my other source files. The following are the steps I would do to try and convert a .js file into a .tsx file:

1. Rename .js file to a .tsx file
2. Restart the app with `npm start`
3. Go through and fix the typescript issues, whether compilation errors or not defining types for the type checker.

Rinse and repeat

Here is a specific problem I've encountered with various attempts to convert a .js to a .tsx source file:

```js
//MyNav.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import {Navbar, Nav, Collapse} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const MyNav:React.FC<{}> = () => {
  return(
    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
      <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to={"/"}>BRAND</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Collapse>
        <Nav className="mr-auto">      
          <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/"}>Dashboard</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Collapse>
    </Navbar>
    );
  }
  
export default MyNav;
```

And this is the parent component that has a MyNav component

```js
//App.js <- it is still currently a .js file, I have not changed it to a .tsx
import React from 'react';
import MyNav from './MyNav';
import {HashRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import DashboardPage from './DashboardPage';

function App() {
  //...

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <HashRouter>
        <MyNav />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/">
            <DashboardPage
              {/*various props being passed*/}
            />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

And the error I get while converting MyNav.tsx:

> [tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\kde-embed-soft-dev\Projects\kde-origin-connect\src\MyNav.tsx(28,5)
> [0]       TS2769: No overload matches this call.
> [0]   The last overload gave the following error.
> [0]     Argument of type '{ bg: string; expand: "lg"; __self: undefined; __source: { fileName: string; lineNumber: number; columnNumber: number; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Attributes & NavbarProps'.
> [0]       Object literal may only specify known properties, and '__self' does not exist in type 'Attributes & NavbarProps'.

The first line tells me the line number I should go look at but it points to a line that looks nonsensical in terms of pointing to the actual error.

More information on my project settings, I am still learning about webpack, but I've put in the rules to look for .ts and .tsx files to use with `ts-loader` as well as taking .js files into a `source-map-loader` loader (though I'm not seeing a .map file anywhere in my project).

I've set up a basic tsconfig.json file which looks like this:

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "mapRoot": "./dist",
    "types": ["node"],
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules", "user_data", "scripts"],
  "include": ["src", "electron"]
}
```

and the dev-dependencies for types look like this in my `package.json` file:

```json
//package.json
{
//...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.14",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-bootstrap": "^0.32.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.6",
    "electron": "^10.1.3",
    "electron-builder": "^22.8.1",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^2.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.12",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

I started with leaf-like modules, files that don't depend on others. Then I moved on to a module that had a dependency and the error messages became vague with error line numbers that didn't match up with my file, or even past the total lines in the file. I understand (or maybe I don't) that the the error must be referring to the compiled tsx file, but I am unable to find/know where that file exists in my project.

**Question**

1. Why am I not able to use React components from libraries like React Bootstrap, ie, what did I miss/completely not do to solve the error of matching the overload. I do not understand what the __self represents in the error message.
2. Why am I getting the wrong line number with the error messages, what could have I not done correctly/missed in enabling typescript on my ejected CRA electron app?
3. When configuring webpack, am I going to have issues adding in loaders as I did when the ejected CRA has babel/other loaders already in?

Thank you for your time and effort.